# Behaviour of `__str__` method of type `complex`

Tags: python

So I was typing random stuff in my Python shell, and saw this:

```py
>>> print(-1j)
(-0-1j)
```

Which troubled me. So and continued and tried something else and saw:

```py
>>> print((-0-1j))
-1j
```

(I do know the extra parentheses are redundant, they’re there for comical effects)

Immediately looking at this, it reminded me of all the JavaScript type-casting memes and the related questions on SO, so I posted [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/s0b9mt/javascript_but_python/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) meme on reddit.

But I am still puzzled by this behaviour, which I believe is caused by the `complex.__str__` method.

I couldn’t find any documentation related to it, so can someone please explain to me what really is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not have a separate imaginary number type, or a separate Gaussian integer type. All imaginary numbers are represented as complex numbers, and all complex number components are floating point.

IEEE 754 floating point has a `-0.0` value, which can be a complex number component. `complex.__repr__` will omit a real component of regular 0.0, but not -0.0, and will format integer-valued components without a `.0`. Unfortunately, that leads to the output you see.

`-1j` is a `-` operator applied to `1j`, and `1j` is a complex number with real part `0.0` and imaginary part `1.0`. In other words, `1j` is `complex(0.0, 1.0)`.

Negating `1j` produces a real part of `-0.0` - floating point negative zero - and an imaginary part of `-1.0`. In other words, `-1j` is `complex(-0.0, -1.0)`, which displays as `-0-1j`, displaying the -0.0 but dropping the `.0`s.

However, integers don't have negative zero, so `-0` is just `0`. `-0-1j` subtracts `1j` from `0`. After converting `0` to complex, both real components are `0.0`, so the subtraction produces a real component of `0.0 - 0.0`, which is regular `0.0` instead of `-0.0`. The result is `complex(0.0, -1.0)`, which displays as `-1j`.